# Create several MySQL tables from a loop?

Tags: php, mysql

This is the code:

```
<?php
$months= array("january", "november", "december");
$db_server = include('root.php');
if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('info');
for ($i=0; $i < $months; $i++){
    $query1 = "CREATE TABLE {$months[$i]} (
    StIDf CHAR(10) NOT NULL, FulNam TEXT NOT NULL, ComNam TEXT NOT NULL,Add TEXT ,Tel TEXT )";
}
?>
```

But it's not working. I need to create several tables from one loop. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Please don't do that. Just have one table and add an extra column for the month.

Comment: my table is really big to type and it makes the coding so big so i thought to make a table via loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$months    = array("january","november","december");
$db_server = include('root.php');

if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('info');

foreach($months as $month) {
    $query1 = "CREATE TABLE {$month}  ( "
            . "StIDf CHAR(10) NOT NULL, "
            . "FulNam TEXT NOT NULL, "
            . "ComNam TEXT NOT NULL, "
            . "Add TEXT, "
            . "Tel TEXT "
            . ")";
    $result = mysql_query($query1);
}
?>
```

Your code was not executing the `mysql_query` (or the alternatives from mysqli or PDO) so nothing was executed in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You are never performing the actual query, add this line to inside the for-loop:

`mysql_query($query1);`

Also, you should use `count($month)` to find out how many items it contains.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($months); $i++) {
    $query1 = "CREATE TABLE {$months[$i]}  (
    StIDf CHAR(10) NOT NULL,FulNam TEXT NOT NULL, ComNam TEXT NOT NULL,Add TEXT ,Tel TEXT )";
    mysql_query($query1);
}
```

Also, I suggest using `mysqli` or `mysql PDO` instead of the old, will be deprecated in the future, mysql API. Read more about that here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: i was just started php
i'll try mysqli